# redirect all `*` to specific path in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a single landing page `nextJs` application it is possible to redirect all `*` to specific routes as we do in `react-router` like this how can I do exactly the same in `nextJs`

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={ROUTES.ROOT} element={<Registry />} />
        <Route path={ROUTES.ALL} element={<Navigate to={ROUTES.ROOT} />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

```
export const ROUTES = {
  ALL: '*',
  ROOT: '/registry',

};
```

what I have done so far is that I'm able to redirect a specific route to specific route but not able to redirect all routes to a specific route

```
const nextConfig = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/path', // not able to "*" the route
        destination: '/registry', // Matched parameters can be used in the destination
        permanent: false,
      },
    ];
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, nextJs doesn't seems to have a proper way to handle this kind of redirection inside the nextConfig, But if you want to redirect any 404 page to home, what you can do is:

1. Create a custom 404 page inside the **pages**, note that your page **must** be named as **404**
2. Add this snippet in the 404 file.

---

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
export default function Custom404() {
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    router.replace('/')
  })

  return null
}
```

With that any not found route should redirect to home page.
[See this discussion on github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16749)

**edit:**
One last thing, if you want to handle some kind of logic when a user visit some route and redirect if fail, you can do so with **getServerSideProps**:

1. Add the async function **getServerSideProps** in the page where you want to handle some kind of logic before render the page:

---

```
// Page where you want to handle the logic
// data is the props that comes from getServerSideProps
function Page({ data }) {
  // Render data...
}


// This gets called on every request
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // fetch some data from external API
  const res = await fetch(`https://someapi/fetchData`)
  const data = await res.json()
  
  if(!data) {
    // Here we redirect the user to home if get some error at the API
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false
      }
    }
  }

  // Otherwise pass the data to Page as props
  return { props: { data } }
}
export default Page
```

It's just an example but you got the idea, if you want to learn more about this, [read the docs here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)